# How to plot a subset of a data frame in R?

Tags: r, plot, subset

Is there a simple way to do this in R:

```
plot(var1,var2, for all observations in the data frame where var3 < 155)
```

It is possible by creating a new data  `newdata <- data[which( data$var3 < 155),]` but then I have to redefine all the variables `newvar1 <- newdata$var1` etc.

Comment: You don't need `which` -- in fact you shouldn't use it from performance reasons. It converts bool index to numerical one, yet you can use both equally well to subset the data frame.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`with(dfr[dfr$var3 < 155,], plot(var1, var2))` should do the trick.

**Edit** regarding multiple conditions:

```
with(dfr[(dfr$var3 < 155) & (dfr$var4 > 27),], plot(var1, var2))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried this but it just outputs the plot as if the restriction var3<155 is not there.

Comment: Well, I tried it with a data.frame created like this: `dfr<-data.frame(var1=rnorm(100), var2=rnorm(100), var3=rnorm(100, 160, 10))`, and it worked flawlessly. Perhaps something else is in your way? Or perhaps all your observations have var3 < 155 ?

Comment: It worked,thanks. (my problem was I had already defined var1 and var2 as the full vectors earlier). Also, Is it possible to have more than one condition, e.g var4 > 27 ?

Comment: or `with(subset(df,var3<155 & var4>27), plot(var1,var2))`

Answer (score 12):

Most straightforward option:

```
plot(var1[var3<155],var2[var3<155])
```

It does not look good because of code redundancy, but is ok for fast`n`dirty hacking.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I would do it, in order to get in the var4 restriction:

```
dfr<-data.frame(var1=rnorm(100), var2=rnorm(100), var3=rnorm(100, 160, 10), var4=rnorm(100, 27, 6))
plot( subset( dfr, var3 < 155 & var4 > 27, select = c( var1, var2 ) ) )
```

Rgds,
Rainer

Comment: Thanks, it works. Is it possible to plot functions of the variables in this way? e.g. log(var1)  or  var1/var2

Comment: @jamie314 - not sure what you exactly want to achieve but I think you have to assign the subset to a new variable first `dfr1 <- subset( dfr, var3 < 155 & var4 > 27, select = c( var1, var2 ) )`, then you can do stuff like `plot( dfr1$var2, dfr1$var1 / dfr1$var2 )`

Answer (score 1):

This chunk should do the work:

```
plot(var2 ~ var1, data=subset(dataframe, var3 < 150))
```

My best regards.

How this works:

1. Fisrt, we make selection using the subset function. Other possibilities can be used, like, subset(dataframe, var4 =="some" & var5 > 10). The "**&**" operator can be used to select all "some" **and** over 10. Also the operator "**|**" could be used to select "some" **or** "over 10".
2. The next step is to plot the results of the subset, using tilde (~) operator, that just imply a formula, in this case var.response ~ var.independet. Of course this is not a formula, but works great for this case.

Comment: This looks like a viable solution, however, you might add a comment as to why it works. I personally prefer using `[` to `subset` as it reduces the potential of side effects.