# why / what is a true / false plot?

Tags: r

I got along via [summary(object) works but plot(object) not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44906012/summaryobject-works-but-plotobject-not/44907520#44907520) to plot a subset of a data frame (lots of devices and each with Amplification against Voltage). Now I almost have the wanted result but why is the subset provided with two plots respectively divided into a false and true plot? Is the one plot the one I restricted (true) and the other plot all other subsets (false)?

I plotted it via lattice: `xyplot(Amplification ~ Voltage | Serial_number==912009913, data=before, grid=TRUE)`

(A "true / false plot lattice r" searching or something similar didn't provide me with a(ny) result)

[image: True/false plots]

Comment: the `|` in lattice `xyplot` is *conditional on*, so the FALSE is for devices that are not your serial number, and TRUE is the device you want. If you only want your device, I think the syntax you need is `xyplot(Amplification ~ Voltage, data=before[  before$Serial_number==912009913,], grid=TRUE)`

Comment: @xraynaud Thanks, will try this out in the office! Btw: How do I accept a comment as a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `|` in lattice `xyplot` means *conditional on*, so FALSE corresponds to devices that do not have the serial number 912009913, and TRUE corresponds to the device with serial number 912009913. If you only want a plot for your device, I think the syntax you need is

```
xyplot(Amplification~Voltage, data=before[before$Serial_number==912009913,], 
    grid=TRUE)
```